# Minkowski sums with open and closure operators

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a normed vector space. Let $A,B\subseteq X$, then I want to prove that:
$$
 \begin{matrix}
(i)\; A^{\circ}+B^{\circ}\subset (A+B)^\circ\\
(ii)\; \bar A+\bar B\subset \overline{(A+B)}
\end{matrix}
$$

I have already proved the contention for $(i)\text{ and }(ii)$, but got stucked finding examples that gives me the proper contention. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can find examples in $\Bbb R^1$.

Comment: Ok, what do you think of this for $(i)$:
Lets take $A=\Bbb Q$ and $B=(0,1)\;\Rightarrow A^\circ = \emptyset$ so $A^\circ + B^\circ = \emptyset$. So it suffices to show that $(\Bbb Q+(0,1))^\circ\neq\emptyset$
Lets take $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\in (\Bbb Q + (0,1))$, so taking $r=\frac{1}{5}$ we get that $B_r(\frac{2}{3})\subset (\Bbb Q + (0,1))$ whichs implies that $\frac{2}{3}\in (\Bbb Q+(0,1))^\circ$. Thereby 
$$A^\circ + B^\circ \subset (A+B)^\circ$$

Comment: In fact $Q+(0,1)=R$. It is easy to show that if $A$ is dense in $R,$ and $B$ is a non-empty open subset of $R$ then $A+B=R$.

Comment: Actually $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$ so it holds that $\Bbb Q+(0,1)=\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a proper inclusion in (ii): If $A=\bar A,\; B=\bar B,$ but $A+B$ is not closed, then $A+B\ne \overline {A+B}.$ For example $$A=\{n+(1/2)(1-1/n):n\in N\},\quad  B= Z.$$ Then $1/2\in \overline {A+B}$ and $1/2\not \in A+B=\bar A+\bar B.$

It is necessary to use unbounded $A,\; B $ because if $a_n\in A ,\; b_n\in B,$ and $x=\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_n+b_n)\in \overline {A+B}$, and if $(a_{k_n})_n$ is a convergent subsequence of $(a_n)_n$, then $(b_{k_n})_n$ is also convergent (because $a_{k_n}+b_{k_n}\to x$) which makes $x=(\lim a_{k_n})+ \lim b_{k_n}\in \bar A+\bar B.$

So if $A$ or $B$ is bounded then $\bar A+\bar B=\overline {A+B}.$